# Lifetime issue adding a function pointer to a struct

Tags: rust

I'm trying to add a function pointer to a struct, and can't figure out how to do it. Here is a simple example:

```
struct Ure<'a> {
    num: u64,
    func: Option<&'a Fn(u64) -> u64>,
}

impl<'a> Ure<'a> {
    fn g42_ure(n: u64) -> Ure<'a> {
        Ure {
          num: n,
          func: Some(&Ure::g42),
        }
    }

    fn g42(u: u64) -> u64 {
        if u > 42 { u } else { 42 }
    }
}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:10:23
   |
10 |           func: Some(&Ure::g42),
   |                       ^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
11 |         }
12 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 7:34...
  --> <anon>:7:35
   |
7  |       fn g42_ure(n: u64) -> Ure<'a> {
   |  ___________________________________^ starting here...
8  | |         Ure {
9  | |           num: n,
10 | |           func: Some(&Ure::g42),
11 | |         }
12 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
```

Is there a way to get a reference to function `g42` in this example to live long enough without passing it as an argument to `g42_ure`? It does not matter to me where `g42` is defined (whether it is inside `impl Ure`, `g42_ure()` or neither), but coming from an OOP background it seems neater inside `impl Ure`.

I'm just learning Rust (and very much enjoying it), so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is not a function pointer; it's a reference to a *closure*. Do you actually need an environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Fn(u64) -> u64` is not a function pointer, but a trait (-object). Function pointers in Rust are written `fn(u64) -> u64`, with a **lowercase `f`**! Also note that `fn(u64) -> u64` is *already* a function *pointer*, no need to say `&fn(u64) -> u64`!

So one way to make it work is by using function pointers ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=98a48e75ad6e70a8cef8637ab6af82a0&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
struct Ure {
    num: u64,
    func: Option<fn(u64) -> u64>,
    //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

impl Ure {
    fn g42_ure(n: u64) -> Ure {
        Ure {
            num: n,
            func: Some(Ure::g42),
            //         ^^^^^^^^
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Function pointers have limitations, though. Specifically, they can't have environments like closures have. That's there the `Fn` trait comes in which (together with its siblings `FnMut` and `FnOnce`) abstracts over callable things in general (including function pointers and closures).

The problem is that you can't use trait objects that easily. Probably the easiest is to use a `Box` to store and own a trait object on the heap. It would look like this ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7e97d3f265c131fd6a7bad8c75c65ae9&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
struct Ure {
    num: u64,
    func: Option<Box<Fn(u64) -> u64>>,
    //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

impl Ure {
    fn g42_ure(n: u64) -> Ure {
        Ure {
            num: n,
            func: Some(Box::new(Ure::g42)),
            //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    }   
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that is a very clear and helpful answer. Much appreciated.